# WinError 10061 No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

Tags: python, pymysql

Hola estoy creando un programa y me compre una vps ubuntu 18.04 LTS, el caso es que cuando la conecto al programa me sale el error del titulo, pero cuando lo hago en localhost no falla. Aqui el code

```
      def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host="50.116.58.164",
            user="Usuario",
            password="No la vas a ver xd",
            db="negro_oscuro",
            port=3306
        )

        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

Comment: Yo uso pymysql.

Comment: Probablemente tu VPS tiene reglas en el cortafuegos para impedir la conexión al puerto 3306. Debes investigar cómo añadir reglas para abrir la conexión, aunque no sé si será seguro pues depende de si el tráfico va cifrado o no. Como regla general no deberías exponer tu base de datos a internet, sino accederla sólo desde "localhost". Puedes crear una api REST (por ejemplo usando flask) que haga de intermediaria entre internet y la base de datos.